# Does my USB Cable Transfer Data?

Tags: usb

I have an imperative question. I need to update the firmware of my keyboard, but I'm getting an error. Support thinks I'm using a USB-C to USB-A cable that doesn't transfer data, which is a valid assumption.

I really need to know how exactly how I can test if a USB cable transfers Data or not. In my case, update the firmware, but is there a way I can test if my cable will transfer data? I have so many cables, I don't know what's what. They said to use the factory-supplied cable, but honestly, I don't know where that cable is because I bought a different cable that is angled so there is a better fit.

So since you know the story, exactly how can I tell and test if this cable will transfer data Their website says, there are cables that will power your keyboard and make it work, but it won't transfer data when trying to flash the firmware. I have so many USB devices, I just need a plan to see and test if it will transfer data. I have so many devices and chargers that use USB-C to USB-A so I'm not lacking of stuff I can test with. Is there a program that will tell me? If there is, that would be amazing. I'm using Windows 10 Pro.

Please Help! I need to rule out the error isn't my fault.

Thank you very much.

Comment: Is it a wired keyboard, or a wireless one that only has USB for charging/updates? Is your cable a "USB 3.0" cable on the USB-A end, or a basic non-USB3 one?

Comment: Very unclear. Which model is the keyboard? Which firmware and where did you get it? Why is it urgently required to install a driver, or do you mean the firmware? What is the problem with a USB cable and what is its connection regarding the keyboard problem?

Comment: The only way to know for certain is to get a multimeter and the USB pinouts and make sure that the USB data pins are connected. Failing that you should be able to use another device such as a phone to verify it.

Comment: The usual method is to try another cable.

Comment: “ Is there a program that will tell me?” - There is specialized hardware that could tell you if you have thousands to spend on it.  Guessing you don’t want $15k specialized commercial test stand hardware

Comment: @Mokubai *"The **only way to know for certain** is to get a multimeter and the USB pinouts and make sure that the USB data pins are connected."* -- You exaggerate because that's only a basic test..  That's only a continuity test using a DC voltage.  You neglect to mention testing for shorts.  For certainty you would also need to verify bandwidth capability by testing with AC voltages.

Comment: @sawdust for USB2 over type C grabbing the oscilloscope and doing eye diagrams to measure everything is overkill.  USB 2 is not particularly difficult (I've actually designed it I to a couple of circuits) and is pretty lax by comparison. USB 2 is enough for firmware transfers and you only need to care about the superspeed pairs if a) they are connected at all and b) either device cares about them. A keyboard is unlikely to be USB 3. A multimeter can prove both shorts and open connections and is enough for USB 2.  You want to check the cable has no intermittent connections, a wiggle suffices.

Comment: While expensive equipment would certainly work to test cables, you should be able to use the USB system itself to determine if a cable works.  And expensive equipment will work no better than that for a cable with an intermittent break.

Answer (score 0):

Every USB cable can transfer data AND power.
Whether the equipment on either end sends/receives data or only uses power from the cable depends on the equipment. Not on the cable itself.

A typical (wired) USB keyboard gets data AND power from USB. Data for the keystrokes (and maybe firmware updates or led-controls on a gaming keyboard go the other way) and it receives power to supply its internal electronics.

Some keyboards have a split-cable or Y-cable that has 2 USB plugs on the computer side. In that case 1 plug has data AND power en the other one is power-only. This is typically done on keyboards that for some features (like programmable LEDs) need more power then can be delivered by a single USB connection.

It is possible that your keyboard is one of those and you need BOTH plugs in order to flash the firmware. (For just using it as a keyboard the standard data+power single USB plug is usually enough.)
Your replacement USB cable obviously works for data (or the keyboard wouldn't work at all), but doesn't provide the extra plug.

Importunately those split cables are not official USB specification cables and different manufactures use different wiring schemes for those.
It is possible it will only work with the original cable that came with the keyboard.

If you have a USB socket on your computer with a yellow colored inside it is possible it will work with a standard USB cable on that sockets.
Yellow USB sockets are often able to deliver a bit more power than the normal ones and that might just do the trick.

Comment: There are many "charge only" cables available that lack data pins. If they have a wireless keyboard that needs USB for charging and data for a firmware update then the keyboard would work regardless of the cable.

Comment: @Mokubai  Charge only cables exist, but they are relatively rare and can't be sold as a generic USB cable. Any generic USB cable you buy of the shelf will have charge AND data so they should work. Generic USB-C to USB-A adapters also transfer power AND data, so that shouldn't make any difference either. Without more detail about the posters exact setup I'll leave it at that.

Comment: I'd agree that normally you shouldn't be able to buy charge only cables without them being clearly marked as such, but many devices like bluetooth headphones will never be connected to a computer so they may have charge-only cables supplied with them. You can easily end up with them in your usual rotation of "charging cables" without realising until you go to use them as data cables. Other than that I agree with you. I did not downvote you.

Comment: @Mokubai You seem to know the real answers, how can I award you the answer?. The keyboard manufacturer wouldn't write on their firmware page to ensure you're using the default cable because some cables only charge just for the heck of it or to play mind games with you. I'm not sure why anyone would dispute this. The one answer provided is wrong. Also, the model and why I'm flashing the firmware is irrelevant for the commenter that posted that. I'm pretty sure there is just an issue with the firmware, I thought I'd ask though.

Comment: @user335185 - Why don’t you provide the information then the community can decide if it’s irrelevant

Answer (score -1):

Charge only cables exist that fit in USB sockets. (Are these USB cables? Maybe not.)  I've even seen charge cables with a switch on them so you can enable and disable data as appropriate.   Some security experts suggest using charge only cables at public charging stations to prevent unauthorized access to your devices.

Also, it is possible for a regular USB cable to break (or wear out) to accidentally turn it into a charge only or intermittent data cable.

You can easily test a USB cable to see if it works with data by plugging a device into your computer with it, like a phone or an external disk, and see if either your host or the device recognizes the connection.  If the cable is damaged and intermittent, moving it around may cause the device to disconnect and reconnect randomly.  Some operating systems include a USB explorer that will list all connected usb devices, and possibly display USB connection events.